# playing with Scala lists and Slick

Tags: scala, list, slick

I have in my scala play project a function like:

```
 def teamMainPlayer (teamId: Option[String]): String ={
      val playersList = Players.getAll(p => (p.team === teamId.getOrElse("NULL")) && (p.role === "Main Player") )
      playersList.head.playerId
    } 

}
```

I am getting the error:

```
 value head is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[model.Player]]
```

My goal is to return the id of the player that is  considered the "Main Player"

Comment: Wrap your request around an Await like this: `val playerList = Await.result(Players.getAll(p => (p.team === teamId.getOrElse("NULL")) && (p.role === "Main Player") ), Duration.Inf)`

Answer (score 3):

playersList is a Future containing a list (actually, a Seq). You can either get the value from the Future in a blocking manner (not recommended) or have your function return a Future and do this:

```
playersList.map(_.head.playerId)
```

In either case, I recommend reading more about Futures: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html